# Getting undefined value while inheritance in JavaScript OOPS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

Getting undefined value while inheritance in JavaScript OOPS. Student object doesn't inheritance the Person Object

```js
function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.say = function() {
        return this.name + " says Hi..";
    }
}

var p1 = new person("Mahesh", "33");
var p2 = new person("Girish", "30");

console.log(p1.say());
console.log(p2.say());

// Inheritance 
function student() {};
student.prototype = new person();
var stud1 = new student("Nakktu", "32");

console.log(stud1.say());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to call your super class from within the constructor of the sub class. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Examples) MDN link for more information.

```js
function person(name, age) {
    // When no name is provided, throw an error.
    if (name === undefined) {
      throw 'Unable to create instance of person. Name is required.';
    }
    
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.say = function() {
        return this.name + " says Hi..";
    }
}

var p1 = new person("Mahesh", "33");
var p2 = new person("Girish", "30");

console.log(p1.say());
console.log(p2.say());

// Inheritance 
function student(name, age) {
  // You need to call your super class.
  person.call(this, name, age);
};
// Don't use "new person()", your code will stop working when person() throws
// an error when the 'name' param is required and missing.
student.prototype = Object.create(person.prototype);

var stud1 = new student("Nakktu", "32");
console.log(stud1.say());
```

Comment: Thank you @Thijs. This will help me understand "Inheritance" better. :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer to throw an error when no name is provided. When you change the `student.prototype = ` assignment back to `new person();` you will see the code fails whereas the current implementation still works as intended.